# array_unshift() with empty array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to add an element to the beginning of an array, but this array might be empty sometimes. I've tried using `array_unshift()` but it doesn't seem to like empty arrays... should I simply check for the empty array and append the element manually, or does `array_unshift()` not mind empty arrays but I'm just being a klutz?

Here is my code at the moment:

```
$sids = array();
$sids = explode(",", $sid['sids']);

array_unshift($sids, session_id());
```

The contents of the `$sids` array are taken from a database and are comma separated values.

Thanks,

James

**EDIT**

I've managed to fix this now - sorry everyone!

Here's the updated code:

```
$sids = array();

if(!empty($row['sids']))
{
    $sids = explode(",", $row['sids']);
}

array_unshift($sids, session_id());
```

Comment: Can you post your current code?

Comment: What do you mean "Doesn't like?" Have you initialized the variable (i.e. by using `array()` ) or are you working with an undefined variable?

Comment: There is no problem using `array_unshift()` on an empty array. It works like expected. But it's a problem to call it on a non-array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $sid['sids'] is empty, explode will return FALSE
Then $sids will be equal to FALSE
and the subsequent call to array_unshift will fail.

You should probably make sure $sids is an array before calling array_unshift.
Here's a way to do it:

```
if(!empty($sid['sids']))
  $sids = explode(",", $sid['sids']);
else
  $sids = array();

array_unshift($sids, session_id());
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, your first line of code is pointless; explode always returns a value, whether it be an array or `FALSE`. You're guaranteed to overwrite that value once you call explode.

Secondly, your code *should* work. One minor edit I'd make is this:

```
<?php
$sids = array();
$sids = explode(",", $sid['sids']);
if(is_array($sids))
    array_unshift($sids, session_id());
?>
```

Because (even though your code says otherwise, and that the PHP documentation says otherwise), explode *may not* always return an array.

Another piece of information that may be useful is whether or not there was any error being reported, and, if so, what the error was.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

`array_unshift()` accepts the array parameter by reference. This means it must actually *be a variable*, not an expression like `array()`. It also means it will modify the variable you pass, not return a new array with the element added. Here's an example to illustrate this:

```
$array = array();
array_unshift($array, 42);
var_dump($array); // Array now has one element, 42
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sids = explode(",", $sid['sids']);
if (!is_array($sids)) {
  $sids = array();
}
array_unshift($sids, session_id());
```